# Is this a scratch or a smudge on the sensor?

Tags: sensor, sony, cleaning, scratches

There is this (rather discounted, but still expensive) Sony a7 III that someone is selling and it has this picture:
[image: sensor]
Supposedly it works "flawlessly", but to me the bit circled in blue looks like a smudge, maybe someone hit the sensor with the nozzle of a blower? What do you think, is it likely this is visible in images and likely that it's possible to either get it off myself or have it cleaned professionally for a reasonable (say <$100) price?

The bit circled in green on the left looks like a reflection to me and the bits circled in green on the right like harmless dust.

Comment: Are you referring to the vertical line in the centre, the small crescent moon on the right, the tiny dot bottom right, or the heaped blanket on the left? Which of these are reflections or artifacts, and which are real? If you don't like the look of it, don't buy it.

Comment: The a7 attracts dust like a magnet. Cleaning the sensor is pretty easy. The more important information is, that the shutter curtain edges still look great. This is one achilles heel on this camera.

Comment: @WeatherVane Sorry, I was talking about the vertical line. The rest looks like easy to remove dust or clearly a reflection, at least to me. To be honest I'm probably not buying it anyway for other reasons, I'm just curious.

Comment: Can I assume that you did not take the picture and that you do not have the camera to look at personally?

Comment: Knowing where you are buying it from would go a long way toward helping us guestimate the risk that this is actual damage to the sensor.

Comment: Are there any sample images that were supposedly taken recently, when the sensor was in the same state that it is now?

Answer (score 2):

The two specs highlighted in green on the right look like a droplet residue (upper) and a dust spec (lower).

You probably can use a sensor cleaning kit to remove those two.

I don't what is highlighted in green on the left. It looks like a reflection.

As someone stated about the blue circle, it looks like a reflection.

Reflections should change position as you tilt the camera, and or the change the angle of the light source.

Answer (score 1):

The vertical line looks more like a reflection to me...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you did not take the picture yourself and that these are actually **on** the sensor rather than merely reflections, at the worst, this just looks like a bad cleaning job. It kinda looks as if someone left too much cleaning fluid on the sensor, or their swab had something already dissolved in/on it when they used it on the sensor. A regular cleaning, that you can and should learn how to do yourself, should get it off.

Answer (score 0):

These do appear to be all reflections, but if you aren't sure you can either ask the seller to send you alternate pictures or if you meet up in person you can observe it yourself. Sensor cleaning kits are relatively cheap online as well.